# Angular Template Routing

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am building an angular single page app using node, bower, and express. But, for some odd reason, I cannot seem to get `ngRoute` to work. Nothing seems to be appearing in my `.ng-view` div. Here's my code:

**INDEX.HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Node, NPM and Bower</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="app">

   <h1>My App</h1>

   <div class="ng-view"></div>

   <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
   <script src="./app/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**APP.JS**

```
angular.module("app", ["ngRoute"]).
config(function($routeProvider) {
   $routeProvider
   .when("/", {
      template : "<h1>Home</h1>"
   })
   .when("/about", {
      template : "<h1>About</h1>"
   });
});
```

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Comment: You forgot to include the external file for ngRoute

Comment: The external route? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: Read carefully: external file (not route).  i.e. You are missing a script tag for the ngRoute library, as that functionality is not included in `angular.js` (core Angular).  CDN Example:  `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.9/angular-route.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Oh, I see. Do you know what my reference might look like if I downloaded AngularJS using Bower?

Comment: `<script src="bower_components/angular/angular-route.js"></script>`

Comment: Might also need to `bower install angular-route#X.Y.Z`

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

Comment: Of course! Wow, my bad. I didn't realize Angular-route is a separate package. Just downloaded it and, everything works fine. Thanks!